# Module loading for both WPF/SL

Tags: wpf, silverlight, module, mef

Is there any way how to create an architecture for **loading modules** in both **WPF** 4 and **Silverlight** 4 ?

I would like to

- use MVVM (and Caliburn.Micro)
- load XAML (+ .XAML.cs ?) on demand
- **load ViewModels on demand** (best in one "package" with .XAML)
- unite this architecture for both Silverlight & WPF
- avoid double work :) (for both WPF & Sl)

*Using MEF is probably a good way when I'm able to CHOOSE ONE of systems (WPF/Sl) ?*